# Why is the movie titled "Ghajini"?

Tags: title, ghajini-2005

*[Ghajini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghajini_(2005_film))* (2005) is a Tamil action thriller movie. This is later remade into Hindi with the same name. It is based on Christopher Nolan's *Memento*. The protagonist in Ghajini suffers from [Anterograde amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterograde_amnesia). But the disease is inaccurately depicted in the movie. Sanjay Ramaswamy (Suriya) forgets his memory every 15 minutes.

My question is about **Tamil movie Ghajini**.  Why is the movie titled Ghajini? What is relation between Ghajini and the movie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghajini_(2005_film)#Themes_and_influences)

> "the film's title is a reference to Mahmud of Ghazni, the tenth-century Sultan of Ghaznavid Empire whose name is pronounced "Ghajini" in Tamil."

It goes on to refer the book *"Sutras, Stories and Yoga Philosophy: Narrative and Transfiguration"* by *Daniel Raveh*.

The third [result](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=lj6TDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&dq=ghajini%20memento&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ghajini&f=false) says

> "Murugadoss offers a more down to earth explanation for the title. According to him, the title of his Tamil movie was inspired by the story of Mahmud of Ghazni, the tenth-century Sultan of the Ghaznavid Empire, who invaded and plundered parts of the Indian subcontinent. Ghazni is famous for his persistence, despite several failures. The Tamil pronunciation of Ghazni is Ghajini."

Comment: Nice findings!!

Answer (score 0):

Such a word never existed in Hindi or in any other Indian language.
The name Ghajini is the name of the villain of the film.title of the film is inspired by the story of Mahmud of Ghazni, an ancient invader of India. This person was so persistent in invading India that he continued trying after several failures. In the film too, the protagonist is such persistent in finding out and killing the villain of the film, who had killed his girlfriend, Kalpana (played by Asin). Aamir Khan's Character, is a short-term amnesiac, who cannot remember anything more than fifteen minutes.
I agree with this context which I got from this link --> http://cutewriting.blogspot.com/2008/12/what-is-meaning-of-word-ghajini-story.html?m=1